# Como fazer o jQuery Chosen desconsiderar acentuação no momento da busca?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Desenvolvi um site que usa o [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), e gostaria que ele **não considerasse** os acentos no momento da busca.

Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com vários nomes, e preciso procurar JOSE (digito sem acento), porém gostaria que ele mostrasse o JOSÉ (com acento) também.

Como fazer isto?

Comment: Essa pergunta é muito ampla, pois envolve resolver **dois** problemas distintos: 1) como fazer uma busca ignorando a acentuação; 2) como **integrar** essa busca ao jQuery Chosen. [Fiz uma pergunta separada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3994/2150) para o caso geral, e vou tentar responder o caso específico [do jQuery Chosen] aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você utilize o [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) que possui o mesmo propósito, com layout muito parecido, que já faz isso que você deseja, e ainda prevê uma opção para você alterar programaticamente o código da pesquisa.

Answer (score 2):

Essa biblioteca não oferece nenhuma opção fácil de customizar a busca não... Tentei ler os códigos-fontes [primeiro no GitHub](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) (eles estão em CoffeeScript, linguagem que não domino) [depois no arquivo baixado](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/) (`chosen.jquery.js`), e identifiquei a parte onde ele faz a busca de fato:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.winnow_results = function() {
  ...
  searchText = this.get_search_text();
  escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  regexAnchor = this.search_contains ? "" : "^";
  regex = new RegExp(regexAnchor + escapedSearchText, 'i');
  ...
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      ...
        option.search_match = this.search_string_match(option.search_text, regex);
        ...
            startpos = option.search_text.search(zregex);
            text = option.search_text.substr(0, startpos + searchText.length) + '</em>' + option.search_text.substr(startpos + searchText.length);
            option.search_text = text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos);
```

Minha primeira tentativa foi modificar o `get_search_text` para ignorar a acentuação. Para isso, peguei a instância do `Chosen` e substituí o método:

```
var Chosen = $("#meu-select").chosen().data("chosen");

var get_search_text = Chosen.get_search_text;
Chosen.get_search_text = function() {
    return replaceSpecialChars(get_search_text.apply(this));
};
```

(a função `replaceSpecialChars` veio [dessa resposta do @Leonardo Cardoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3995/215); não está completa, para uma versão definitiva acompanhe [a pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3994/215))

Com isso, o **termo de busca** agora ignora a acentuação. O próximo passo seria fazer com que o termo **sendo buscado** ignorasse também. Para isso, modifiquei de forma semelhante o `search_string_match`:

```
var search_string_match = Chosen.search_string_match;
Chosen.search_string_match = function(search_string, regex) {
    return search_string_match(replaceSpecialChars(search_string), regex);
}
```

[Aqui está o resultado](http://jsfiddle.net/3U9Fv/) (veja o código no final). Funciona, mas o problema é que na hora de **realçar** o termo buscado, ele apresenta problemas - uma vez que a regex original não casa o termo original. Pelo código acima, não consigo ver uma maneira de interpor o `replaceSpecialChars` de uma forma que não cause esse problema, mas quando tiver um tempo volto a olhar isso. Por enquanto, fica como resposta parcial... (*Edição:* desisti! Se quiser continuar de onde eu parei, investigue o método `result_add_option`. Mas creio que a maneira mais "sã" seria editar os fontes diretamente...)

Comment: Sua resposta ajudou bastante! Muito obrigado! +1

Comment: Poderia dar uma olhada nesta dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177343/31016  Muito obrigado!