# Chosen Jquery: remover seleção ao teclar DEL

Tags: javascript, jquery, chosen-jquery-plugin

No exemplo [Chosen - Allow Deselect on Single Selects](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#allow-deselect-on-single-selects) é implementada a possibilidade de desmarcar a seleção. Porém a mesma só funciona com o Mouse, ou seja, com o teclado não tem (não descobri) como remover a seleção.

Por este motivo, estou querendo implementar no [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), um método para que ao pressionar a tecla DEL, o valor preenchido seja removido (limpo, ou seja, remover a seleção sem utilizar o mouse).

Então escrevi uma pequena função que aplica o Chosen (configurações citadas nos exemplos oficiais para o Chosen funcionar), além disso, ela também testa qual tecla foi pressionada, e se for a tecla "DEL", chamo o método `limparChosen`, cujo código segue abaixo:

```
 $('#meu_select').trigger('chosen:clear');
```

Para acionar `_this.results_reset(evt);`, que está dentro de `Chosen.prototype.register_observers = function () {`, eu adicionei ao arquivo `chosen.jquery.js`, o seguinte trecho dentro de `Chosen.prototype.register_observers = function () {`, logo abaixo de  `this.form_field_jq.bind("chosen:close.chosen", function(evt) {`, mais ou menos a partir da linha 699 do arquivo original, o seguinte trecho:

```
this.form_field_jq.bind("chosen:clear.chosen", function (evt) {
    _this.results_reset(evt);
});
```

Para utilizar, testo se a tecla DEL foi pressionada, e caso positivo, executo:

```
$('#meu_select').trigger('chosen:clear');
```

Com isso, tudo funciona adequadamente.

Porém, quero uma forma alternativa de implementar a funcionalidade acima citada sem ter que alterar o código fonte do Chosen, pois sempre que atualizar o Chosen, terei que editar o arquivo. O que seria chato e fácil de esquecer.

Como faço para implementar esta funcionalidade sem ter que alterar o código fonte do Chosen?

Comment: Não seria o caso de fazer manualmente um pequeno script para isso sem mexer no chosen? <script> ... faz um onkey com if tecla = del, se for executa o método, e descarta o evento, senão dexa o evento ser tratado pelo JS normalmente </script> - Não consigo ver isso agora pq tou de saida, mas se montar um http://codepen.io/pen com  o chosen, e deixar o link nos comments, eu ou algum outro colega pode testar algo pra postar como resposta aqui, facilita pra gente.

Comment: Isso já foi feito, mas para tirar a seleção não funciona. Só consegui inserindo o BIND acima citado no chosen.jquery.js

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta para deixar mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer um script externo para isso, ou numa tag `script` conforme a conveniência:

```
$("#foco")[0].addEventListener('keyup',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {  
        $("#escolha").val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true )
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/oBLyOp)**.

- `id="foco"` é a div que engloba o *dropdown*;
- `id="escolha"` o elemento onde o Chosen está trabalhando;
- o código da tecla <kbd>DEL</kbd> usualmente é 46, mas só testei no Windows, é bom conferir.

Note que não existe um *trigger* clear, para isto mudamos o valor com `.val`, e acionamos o `chosen:updated` para ele refletir o novo valor.

A idéia de usar um `addEventListener` foi uma dica preciosa do @bfavaretto para evitar a necessidade de fazer um `chosen:close`, conforme eu havia postado na versão original do código.

Clique no link do comentário para mais detalhes:

> *"O truque é interceptar o evento na [fase de captura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21456/quando-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-capturar-eventos-do-dom) – o `true` passado ao `addEventListener` força isso."* – bfavaretto ♦

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção... Com o trigger _this.results_reset(evt); fica bem elegante... não abre nem nada.... mas não consigo chamar ele de fora.

Comment: Agora ficou bem legal, e continua 100% independente do source como era a idéia original. Teste, e qualquer coisa comente.

Comment: O truque é interceptar o evento na [fase de captura](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21456/quando-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-capturar-eventos-do-dom) – o `true` passado ao `addEventListener` força isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agradeço muito a generosidade do Bacco e do bfavaretto!!! Ficou muito bom!